# nodejs typescript copy value of existing properties from one object to another

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have an object1 with the properties `name, value, desc` and I have a object2 with the properties `name, value, desc, time, frame, getName, ...`.

Now I want to create a new object1 but with all the values of object2 from properties that also exist in object1.

For example:

```
class Object1 {
  name!: string;
  value!: number;
  desc!: string;
}

class Object2 {
  name!: string;
  value!: number;
  desc!: string;
  time!: date;
  frame!: number;
}

let object2: Object2 = getMyObject();
// object2 has now name: "test", value: 5, desc: "testDesc", time: "27-03-2023", frame: 7, getName: function(), [...]

let object1: Object1 = new Object1();

fillValuesFromObject(object1, object2) // This should fill all the values of existing properties

console.log(object1); // name: "test", value: 5, desc: "testDesc"
// So all other properties from object2 that object1 doesn't have are ignored
```

How can I make this `fillValuesFromObject`?

Comment: What's `Object1`? It appears to be a class, because you're instantiating it with `new`. `Object2` on the other hand seems to be an object literal.

Comment: They are both classes. I just did it like that to make an example

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and a clear description of what you're trying to achieve. For now, we're left to fix your broken class definitions.

Comment: Where are the class definitions broken?

Comment: Depending on your TS compiler settings, [everywhere](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgRmgbwFDWgDswBbZALmgjQCcBLQgcwBp9oA3MEAVwqO5LxkNVgQAmyCMErV6TXAF9cuUJBgIU6AEw42xMjNoMWbTjz6EBQkWwlTDckwTR0D0MWDTJR0AGY1SCythH0ZkNAA5QMpfbkJ0OgB7QgAKAEofAG0AOlyAXUUgA)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
When I wrote the answer to the question, it was not clear what the author wanted to achieve until the end. Currently, reading the question, I would offer him a completely different solution.

```
function fillValuesFromObject<KType, KType2>(obj1: KType, obj2: KType2, keysToCopy: ((keyof KType) & (keyof KType2))[]) {
  for (const key of keysToCopy) {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key] as any;
  }
}

fillValuesFromObject(object1, object2, ['name', 'desc', 'value'])
```

---

Old answer:

The first question that arises is whether the objects you are copying are to be copied by reference or cloned? The easiest option for duplicating an object is to simply use the spread operator:

```
const newObject = {...oldObject};
```

Spreed operator does not clone the prototype of the object, so only an object with the same shape will be created, but it will not have a common `prototype`. You can set the prototype of the new object to be treated as the same class using (but it's better not to use it if you care about the performance of this solution):

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(newObject, oldObject);
```

Another option for cloning an object is to use the static assign method from the Object class (it also works on classes):

```
const newObject: Object1 = Object.assign(new Object1(), oldObject);
```

Both of these methods will copy the values 1:1, just beware of the nested objects inside, because they will be copied as a reference, that is, editing a nested object in `oldObject` will also change the value in `newObject` due to the reference to the same object

Read more about [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

If you would like to clone an object completely, including its nested objects, you can use the `deepClone` method from the [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) dependency.

```
const {deepClone} = require('lodash');
const newObject = deepClone(oldObject);
```

Comment: But those are creating an 1:1 copy and copy properties from object2 to object1 that object1 doesn't have

Comment: Robby have you checked it out or is that just your guess? Because I've tested it with the TypeScript compiler and there is no problem with either of these solutions

Comment: Update: When I wrote the answer to the question, it was not clear what the author wanted to achieve until the end. Currently, reading the question, I would offer him a completely different solution

Comment: Is it possible to generate `obj1Keys` dynamicly? I want to use that function with other objects aswell. I also get this error on the line in the for loop `Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)`

Comment: Here as an example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgRmgbwFDWgDswBbZAQgC5oI0AnAS0IHMBufaANzBAFcLqhXiXjI67AgBNkEYFRr0mzXAF9cuUJBgIU6AEw4OxMvNqMWErj37yhIsZemzTiixzQMT1ACJg0ySwAzOlIBImFRcVV1EGQ0aAB7JFQ0PWodFIMAXiJkAHc4ZP0ACgBKdiTdVIA6Y2RoHIAif1pGiqKap2AG6GaZNG8ZYDbcSszqjzIewnzoX38y9qq9au4+epyAVnZcWPix9Ax0jqwcmYKMw8X1XDQATwAHeoBrZDuIU+hXu4TAwqqMOx7k8vm8INlQT8-pdUkDHvVgAkSCQEoQANJgnrfD7QABkkPBO0CvEI6AYqOggQYIBAADVrDIAGJ0JEw4qVI7-FIYAA0iSQaS5+lKhgIiMItH5iAwGPe1ERyNRsogAG0ALo9FUAcjqWr5WrW-D10C1XS1aqCCTo0GK4sl30Sfw5ypFeAIBA5KodkEhvyFmA1OUqei9b2gPu+fphegtHDUKiAA